# Prove that $7 | (3^{2n} − 2^{n} )$ for every nonnegative integer $n$.

Tags: solution-verification

I tried to format my question but I couldn’t figure out how to do it.

> Prove that $7 | (3^{2n} − 2^{n})$ for every nonnegative integer $n$.

**my proof:**

Basic step (0): 7 | 1-1 which is true.

Ind. step:
if $p(k) \implies p(k+1)$:

$3^{2k} − 2^{k}=7x$

$3^{2(k+1)} − 2^{k+1}=$

$3^{2k+2} − 2^{k+1}=$

$3^{2k}3^{2} - 2^{k}*2=$

$3^{2}(7x)*2= $ ****is this step correct?****

$9*(7x)*2=$

126x which can be written as 7(18x) and therefore is divisible by 7.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Use $x=9$ and $y=2$ in $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+y^{n-1}).$

Answer (score 4):

You can notice that $3^{2n}=9^n$  and $9=2[7]$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use for the induction step $3^{2n+2}-2^{n+1}=9*3^{2n}-2*2^n=9(3^{2n}-2^n)+7*2^n$

and then the induction hypothesis!

**Edit**: long explanation for the 2nd step:$9*3^{2n}-2*2^n=(9*3^{2n}-2*2^n)-7*2^n+7*2^n=9*3^{2n}-9*2^n+7*2^n=9(3^{2n}-2^n)+7*2^n$

Comment: I understand how the middle side came, but the right side how?

Comment: add and subtract $-7*2^n$!

Comment: why did you add and subtract $-7*2^n$ from where did -7 came?

Comment: I added an extra explanation! @JackSymBol

Comment: it comes out of nowhere, you just add and subtract the same thing such that it is again $0$. do 10 of these exercises and you'll get the hang of it...

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\because 3^{2 n}-2^n &=9^n-2^n \\
&=(9-2)\left(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2} \cdot 2+9^{n-3} \cdot 3+\cdots+2^{n-1}\right) \\
&=7\left(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2} \cdot 2+9^{n-3} \cdot 3+\cdots+2^{n-1}\right) \\
\therefore 7|3^{2 n} &-2^n
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\because 3^{2 n}-2^n=9^n-2^n \equiv 2^n-2^n \equiv 0(\bmod 7)
$$
$$\therefore 7|3^{2n}-2^n$$